# Calculate zscore relative to specific values

Tags: mysql, sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

My goal is to be able to group the sample data below by website by minute, calculate the resulting data's [zscore/standard score](https://www.statisticshowto.com/probability-and-statistics/z-score/#:%7E:text=Simply%20put%2C%20a%20z%2Dscore,on%20a%20normal%20distribution%20curve.) for the number of requests, and add it to separate column.

Right now the data is broken into timestamps with granularity by seconds

```
website             timestamp               requests   
--------   -----------------------------   -----------  
espn.com   2020-08-12T16:00:01.000+00:00       4
yahoo.com  2020-08-12T16:00:01.000+00:00       5
espn.com   2020-08-12T16:00:02.000+00:00       10
yahoo.com  2020-08-12T16:00:02.000+00:00       4
espn.com   2020-08-12T16:01:01.000+00:00       1
yahoo.com  2020-08-12T16:01:01.000+00:00       2
espn.com   2020-08-12T16:01:02.000+00:00       3
yahoo.com  2020-08-12T16:01:02.000+00:00       4
```

This would then be grouped into:

```
website             timestamp               requests   
--------   -----------------------------   -----------  
espn.com       2020-08-12 16:00:00              14
yahoo.com      2020-08-12 16:00:00              9
espn.com       2020-08-12 16:01:00              4
yahoo.com      2020-08-12 16:01:00              6
```

Then final result would look like:

```
website             timestamp               requests     zscore
--------   -----------------------------   -----------  -------- 
espn.com       2020-08-12 16:00:00              14        0.707
yahoo.com      2020-08-12 16:00:00              9         0.707
espn.com       2020-08-12 16:01:00              4        -0.707
yahoo.com      2020-08-12 16:01:00              6        -0.707
```

The zscore is only comparing the request for the current minute to the other rows for the matching website. For example, the zscore for the first row would be:

```
(14 - Average requests for espn.com (9)) / Standard Deviation for espn.com(7.07)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use aggregation and window functions:

```
select website, date_trunc(minute, timestamp), sum(requests),
       (sum(requests) - avg(sum(requests)) over (partition by website)) / 
       nullif(stddev(sum(requests)) over (partition by website), 0)
from t
group by website date_trunc(minute, timestamp)
```

Comment: @LukeSchoenberger . . . As I would anywhere, using `NULLIF()`.